# Illustrator export to Photoshop is changing object scale

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, export, resize

I have several layers in Illustrator, all of them on an A1 canvas.

When I export my layers, one by one, to photoshop format (.psd), and I add them as layers on my photoshop A1 canvas, they just adjust to the whole canvas, thereby losing the original scale.

My canvas/layer is 500ppi in illlustrator, and I export them in 500ppi.

How can I avoid this?

Comment: You could try this: *Edit > Preferences > General*, then uncheck the option *"Resize Image During Place"*

Comment: *"canvas/layer is 500ppi in illustrator"* no, it isn't. Illustrator has no "ppi" settings or options for the canvas.

Answer (score 1):

Illustrator always uses 72 ppi when showing pixel/point measurements. It's a vector app, so only raster items within it include a ppi. Otherwise, we just export vector art at the intended resolution of our final design.

So if you export a 1 inch square at 500 ppi, it will appear as 72x72 pixels in Illustrator and 500x500 pixels in Photoshop. However, the art has not actually been scaled at all, as 1 inch in Ai will still be 1 inch in Ps. The difference in pixel dimensions is only due to the program's assumption of 72 ppi.

For this reason it's best to create vector art at a standardized unit, such as mm or inches when scale is a concern.